# Act as taggable Tags are not displayed on my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, acts-as-taggable

I'm using activeadmin and act as taggable gem. When I insert tags on activeadmin it saves the tags but is not displaying the tags in the view

activeadmin model:

```
   ActiveAdmin.register Project do      
     index do
        column :id
        column :name
        column :created_at
        column :tag_list
        default_actions  
    end

    form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
        f.inputs do
        f.input :name
        f.input :tag_list, :label => "Tags", :hint => 'Comma separated'
        f.input :content, :input_html => {:class => "ckeditor"}
        f.input :image, :as => :file
    end
        f.buttons
    end 
   end
```

model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :image, :tag_list
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  acts_as_taggable

  def previous_project
    self.class.first(:conditions => ["name < ?", name], :order => "name desc")
  end

  def next_project
    self.class.first(:conditions => ["name > ?", name], :order => "name asc")
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <figure class="d1-d3">
        <%= image_tag project.image_url(:thumb) if project.image? %>
        <figcaption>
            <h4><%= link_to project.name, project %></h4>
            <% project.tag_list %>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
<% end %>
```

I tried to use `<%= project.tags %>` and it didn't work either

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this into your Project model (below acts_as_taggable)

```
acts_as_taggable_on :tags
```

And remember to run the migrations, example:

```
create_table :tags do |t|
  t.string :name
end

create_table :taggings do |t|
  t.references :tag

  # You should make sure that the column created is
  # long enough to store the required class names.
  t.references :taggable, :polymorphic => true
  t.references :tagger, :polymorphic => true

  # limit is created to prevent mysql error o index lenght for myisam table type.
  # http://bit.ly/vgW2Ql
  t.string :context, :limit => 128

  t.datetime :created_at
end

add_index :taggings, :tag_id
add_index :taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context]
```

Comment: Thanks dude! It works in the show view, but it doesn't work in index view

Comment: Are you sure that you run the migrations?

Comment: Yes I run the migrations and still no luck

Comment: Hello Sorry for all the inconvenience it was the most silly thing ever! I missed to include the = sign. Anyway thanks for your help guys  really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
  row :tags do
    resource.tag_list.join(", ")
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view missed the equal sign

View:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <figure class="d1-d3">
        <%= image_tag project.image_url(:thumb) if project.image? %>
        <figcaption>
            <h4><%= link_to project.name, project %></h4>
            <%= project.tag_list %>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
<% end %>
```